# ASP.NET MVC Session Based Model Binder - Update Value Back to Session

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-binding

Based on Steve Sanderson's sample in his [book](http://books.google.ca/books?id=gzfFQrs_qQAC&pg=PA224&lpg=PA224&dq=mvc%20session%20model%20binder&source=bl&ots=EXGajmo7TN&sig=-TT0cCwtipPMN_FxnVqkhXbXW8A&hl=en&sa=X&ei=KyLgUayzOOaziwK9goBY&ved=0CHcQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=mvc%20session%20model%20binder&f=false), He provided sample how to implement custom model binder by using session. of course it needs to register in global.asax.cs.

```
public class CartModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    private string sessionKey = "Cart";

    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        Cart cart = (Cart)controllerContext.HttpContext.Session[this.sessionKey];
        if (cart == null)
        {
            cart = new Cart();
            controllerContext.HttpContext.Session[this.sessionKey] = cart;
        }

        return cart;
    }
}
```

The mode class

```
public class Cart
{
    private List<int> itemList;

    public List<int> ItemList
    {
        get
        {
            return this.itemList;
        }
    }

    public Cart()
    {
        this.itemList = new List<int>();
    }

    public void AddItem(int itemId)
    {
        this.itemList.Add(itemId);
    }
}
```

Then in the controller/action to use it:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(Cart cart)
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddToCart(Cart cart, int id)
    {
        cart.AddItem(id);

        return View(cart);
    }
}
```

`Index.cshtml` view

```
@model MvcApplication2.Models.Cart

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        @using (@Html.BeginForm("AddToCart", "Home")) {
        <h1>Cart form</h1>
            @Html.TextBox("id")

            <input type="submit" />
        }
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

`AddToCart.cshtml` view

```
@model MvcApplication2.Models.Cart

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>AddToCart</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        @foreach (int itemId in Model.ItemList)
        { 
            @Html.Label(itemId.ToString())<br />
        }
        @Html.ActionLink("Go back", "Index")
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

But my question here is I don't see any code to update value back to session. How does it happen?

Comment: After you update the Cart in your controller, you can save it back to Session. Is that what you are asking?

Answer (score 0):

You need to save it back to Session in your controller:

```
public RedirectToRouteAction AddToCart(Cart cart)
{
    cart.AddItem(newItem);

    HttpContext.Session["Cart"] = cart;
}
```

UPDATE:
Session variables are stored in a SessionStateItemCollection object that implements IEnumerable and ICollection. When you save an object in the Session, only a reference to the object is stored, not a new instance of it. So, when you make changes to the object, you are actually making changes to the same object that is in your Session (a reference to it is stored in the Session). This is just like creating an object and adding it to a List. When you update the object after adding it to the List, you are actually updating the same instance in the List.

So, in this case, you don't have to save the Cart back to the Session, because the model binder creates a new Cart only when there's no Cart in the Session, so as long as the Session is active, there is one and only one Cart object.

Comment: No, his example has no manipulate of session directly in action. But the value does get updated back to session.

Comment: The session has to be updated somewhere, either in the Action or in the AddItem method of the Cart class. There's no other option. And, in my opinion, it's a better idea to updated it in the controller action.

Comment: here, this.sessionKey = "Cart" only, why your again hard coding it to "Cart"

Comment: The `sessionKey = "Cart"` was in the ModelBinder, not in the Action.

Comment: @ataravati Please see my updated post, you can run it from your environment - go to home/index to add item to cart several time, you will see all items are persisted properly. But there is NO code to manipulate session directly in action.

Comment: That's because a reference to the cart object is saved in the Session, not a new object. So, when you make changes to the cart, you are actually making changes to the same object that is in your Session (a reference to it is stored in the session). And, the model binder creates a new Cart only when there's no Cart in the session, so as long as the session is active, there is one and only one Cart object.